Using Curve ID to drive Random Value Node for Instances
I've instanced a Curve Circle at the end of two splines, which are part of the same geometry. I'd like to assign a random number between 0 to 5 to the Resample Curve count, before it's instanced at the end of the spline. I want the random value ID to be driven by the Curve Index (or ID), so that each individual spline will have curve circle with a curve count that is a random value between 0-5. I have the below set-up, which changes the curve count when the seed is changed - but it doesn't give a random count per Curve Index.

This is a clunky work-around to try and demonstrate the end result I'm trying to achieve

Any help would be greatly appreciated!


Of course your setup gives a random count per curve index. The only problem is, the object you plug into the Instance on Points node is a single object, which will be instanced.
Instancing is basically cloning a given object, so the instances inherit the (single) random value from the original object. If you want them to have an individual count per index, you have to plug a Realize Instances node after the instancing, then the circles are "real" independent geometry and you can give them random counts. Here a simplified setup:


Thank you! My brain was telling me this was sending only one instance per spline but it makes sense you need to realize afterwards to alter each - thanks again =)
